# Relacionamento de tabela - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Boa Tarde!

Tenho as tabelas "Ordem de Serviço" e "Anexo".
Na minha tabela "Ordem de Serviço", quero ter possibilidade de anexar a ordem de serviço escaneada e poder anexar fotos do equipamento.

Ordem de serviço

```
[Table("OrdemDeServico")]
public class OrdemDeServico
{
    public OrdemDeServico()
    {

        OrdemEscaneada = new Anexo();
        FotosDoEquipamento = new List<Anexo>();
    }


    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? OrdemEscaneada_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Ordem de Serviço")]
    [ForeignKey("OrdemEscaneada_Id")]
    public virtual Anexo OrdemEscaneada { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Anexo> FotosDoEquipamento { get; set; }
...
```

Agora a de Anexo

```
public class Anexo
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Byte[] Arquivo { get; set; }

}
```

Consigo adicionar e remover a ordem escaneada sem problemas. Sei que seria melhor colocar o relacionamento na tabela "Anexo", mas não consigo fazer isso de uma boa maneira. Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
 public int? FotosDoEquipamento_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FotosDoEquipamento_Id")]
    public virtual OrdemDeServico FotosDoEquipamento { get; set; }
```

Só que ainda criando "OrdemDeServico_Id", deve ser o relacionamento por conta da ordemEscaneada, mas a chave estrangeira fica em outra tabela, e pensei que não daria problema.

A questão é que não sei como adicionar as fotos. Eu não queria criar outra tabela só para isso, sendo que esta já tem o que preciso.

O design da tabela criada pelo sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: talvez seja eu, mas não entendi bem. `OrdemDeServico` tem um `Anexo`, `Anexo` tem uma `OrdemDeServico`. O mapeamento 1:N deveria funcionar como você fez. O que não está funcionando?

Comment: Agora vi que há duas relações entre as entidades. Isso deve ser o que está causando o problema. Talvez alguém possa, mas eu só conseguiria descobrir rodando o código. Se puder, coloque aqui o esquema do banco de dados gerado pelo seu código.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo. 
OrdemDeServico em uma propriedade OrdemEscaneada do tipo Anexo, e outra FotosDoEquipamento do tipo anexo também.

Isso ficou meio confuso de como fazer o relacionamento.

Comment: Quero usar a mesma tabela "Anexo" tanto para salvar a OrdemEscaneada(Uma unidade), quanto FotosEscaneadas(0 ou x unidades).

Pensei que seria só salvar a o Id da OrdemEscaneada na tabela de OrdemDeServico, e na tabela de Anexo ter um id apontantdo para o Id da ordemDeServico para demonstrar as fotosDoEquipamento

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está bastante fora do padrão, e isto faz com que o Entity Framework possa não funcionar corretamente.

Vou começar pela entidade `OrdemDeServico`:

```cs
[Table("OrdemDeServico")]
public class OrdemDeServico
{
    public OrdemDeServico() // Este construtor não precisa.
    {
        // Estas inicializações não precisam.
        // O Entity Framework inicializa elas para você.
        OrdemEscaneada = new Anexo();
        FotosDoEquipamento = new List<Anexo>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Esta chave estrangeira está fora do padrão. 
    // O correto é OrdemEscaneadaId.
    public int? OrdemEscaneada_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Ordem de Serviço")]
    [ForeignKey("OrdemEscaneada_Id")] // Isto aqui não é necessário.
    public virtual Anexo OrdemEscaneada { get; set; }
    // List implementa ICollection. A recomendação é usar
    // a interface, até para que você tenha mais opções na 
    // hora de iterar os objetos.
    public virtual List<Anexo> FotosDoEquipamento { get; set; }
...
```

Não está incorreto, mas precisa melhorar.

Já `Anexo` não posso afirmar o mesmo. Você definiu os relacionamentos incorretamente. Se `Anexo` pode pertencer a uma ordem de serviço, mas ao mesmo tempo pode conter outra ordem de serviço (por ser uma ordem escaneada), o relacionamento se torna um paradoxo. Pela convenção do Entity Framework, se `OrdemDeServico` contém uma "Ordem Escaneada", então "Ordem Escaneada" não precisa referenciar `OrdemeServico`, mas "Ordem Escaneada" continua sendo um `Anexo`, o que obriga a tabela a ter uma chave.

Isto não é simples de resolver e pede uma abordagem mista. Em primeiro lugar, modifique `Anexo` para sempre pertencer a uma `OrdemDeServico`:

```cs
public class Anexo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrdemServicoId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Byte[] Arquivo { get; set; }

    public virtual OrdemDeServico OrdemDeServico { get; set; }
}
```

Em segundo lugar, deixe `OrdemDeServico` no padrão:

```cs
[Table("OrdemDeServico")]
public class OrdemDeServico
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public int? OrdemEscaneadaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Ordem de Serviço")]
    public virtual Anexo OrdemEscaneada { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Anexo> FotosDoEquipamento { get; set; }
...
```

Na sua classe de contexto, defina o seguinte método, usando a *Fluent API*:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OrdemDeServico>().HasRequired(x => x.OrdemEscaneada)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrdemEscaneadaId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Anexo>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.OrdemDeServico)
        .WithMany(x => x.FotosDoEquipamento)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrdemDeServicoId);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer com .HasOptional() e gera erro, pois não quero que seja obrigatório, pois no primeiro cadastro não terá nada, só depois.

Comment: Erro:One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:DAL.OrdemDeServico_OrdemEscaneada: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'OrdemDeServico_OrdemEscaneada_Target' in relationship 'OrdemDeServico_OrdemEscaneada'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'. DAL.Anexo_OrdemDeServico: :

Comment: Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Anexo_OrdemDeServico_Target' in relationship 'Anexo_OrdemDeServico'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Comment: @EuripedesBarsanulfodeAraujo Pode por favor editar sua pergunta e colocar como está o código até então?

Comment: Estou pensando em criar uma nova tabela só para fotos, esta virando gambiarra demais. Qual sua opinião?

Comment: @EuripedesBarsanulfodeAraujo Minha opinião é que isso deveria ser separado desde o início.

Comment: É que eu uso esta tabela para guarda comprovantes de pagamentos, e vi que para salvar uma ordem de serviço não daria problema algum, mas agora com fotos escaneadas do equipamento esta gerando dor de cabeça.

Vou seguir o seu conselho e separar.

Acho que vou criar uma só pra comprovante, outra para ordem, e outra para fotos, é melhor né? Para "saúde" do banco não seria melhor menos tabela possível? Mas vejo que não pode ferir a "clareza" das tabelas também né?
Sua opinião?

Comment: @EuripedesBarsanulfodeAraujo Vejo como interessante a separação quando ela começa a atrapalhar a modelagem, que é seu caso. Acho que o número de tabelas não influencia na "saúde" do banco. O que influencia são tabelas com muitas linhas.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua opinião ... farei isso.
Como marco sua resposta com correta?